# How would I update a variable continuously and also wait for input at the same time?

Tags: c++, multithreading, time

In my little project, I've decided to create a game that updates a counter of the user's experience points every second, as well as printing a menu and allowing the user to navigate said menu simultaneously. The code to update the user's experience is as follows, and it works perfectly fine standalone.

```
double timerX = GetTickCount();  
double timerY = GetTickCount();  
while(true)                                                                            
{

   double timerZ = GetTickCount() - timerX;
   double timerA = GetTickCount() - timerY;

       if(timerZ >= 1000) {    
        userExperience = userExperience + 1;
        timerX = GetTickCount();
    }
        if(timerA >= 1100) {
            system("CLS");
            refreshExperience();
            timerY = GetTickCount();
        }
```

The function 'refreshExperience()' simply prints the 'userExperience' variable onto the screen using 'cout'.

At the same time as this, my program should be able to display the main menu GUI and ask for input from the user. However, I do not want the asking of input to halt the program, especially the money updater, as it is paramount that that is updated constantly. I have attempted to use multithreading by creating a thread for the 'refreshExperience' function, and also creating a thread for asking for input, but the problem still remained - the money would only update if the user was continually inputting (pressing keys). If he was not, the money would stay the same.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: how do you plan to take user's input? answer may be really different...

Comment: You need to have two threads: GUI thread and a console thread (for user input).

Comment: @Yashas Threads are not (by far) the only way to solve that problem.

Answer (score -1):

Getting input from the user with no discernible break in program execution is only possible in GUI programming. When working in the console, every request for user input will block for the obvious reason that the program has to wait to actually have the necessary data before proceeding.

This is also why you should initialize variables before declaring them; if you don't, stack-allocated variables will contain random (to you) data and the program will not function as intended. Conceptually, this is the same problem the console has, except it doesn't have the luxury of free will and can't simply choose to skip the wait.

Conceptually, programs that have a user interface work by operating with a loop. Every event that occurs, from a mouse movement to a button click, triggers an event in the Window procedure. [In the Win32 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/windowing), it's just a switch statement that checks for each possible event against what actually happened. When there's a match, the system triggers that event handler.

It should be noted that it only *seems* like there is no lag, because usually graphical window procedures are fast enough to seem to respond instantaneously. In reality, any action on the window triggers a calculation by the computer to determine what part of the window was blocked and must be redrawn, as it is now called "invalid."

Lastly, I would highly recommend a different method for the scoreboard update. I know it's just a contrived example for you to experiment with, but that means it's just as good if not better for trying out some design patterns, namely the observer pattern. Rather than the program checking for input every possible clock cycle it can is just a waste. When you have a situation like this, it's common to use [callback functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function), which in C are just function pointers that you pass along. That way you don't have to check to find out when the event is triggered, you can just have the event invoke the function that you passed in as a parameter. [This is how Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/) works, by the way, and how it seems to do so much at once despite being single-threaded.

If you've heard anything about Reactive programming lately -[it's been getting talked about just about everywhere in the C# community these past few months](http://reactivex.io/)- this is what it's talking about, and the reason I bring it up is because this is one of the more common, though trivial, examples of a textbook reactive programming scenario.

Comment: Note that in POSIX-style OS's (read: not Windows), you can read from `stdin` using non-blocking reads.

Comment: "Getting input from the user with no discernible break in program execution is only possible in GUI programming. " - No. That's just plain wrong. You can poll for input and do other things between polling. You can use multiple threads so even if the input thread is blocked others can still do stuff. You can use signals to get asynchronously notified of events and take action based on them. And more. No GUI needed!